# Load child components based on JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to fetch JSON from my server and load components based on my response. I created fetch function like below:

```
export function getMovies() {
    return fetch('https://example.com/get/banner.php',
        {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            return responseData;
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
}
```

I import it in my parent like below and my child component is used in this parent.

```
import { getMovies } from "../../api/get.js";
import BannerScreen from "../comp/banner"; // BannerScreen is child
```

And I use it like below:

```
    return (
<View>
          <BannerScreen getMovies={getMovies} ></BannerScreen>
           <Pressable
                onPress={() =>getMovies()}
           >
               <Text>Refresh</Text>
           </Pressable>
</View>

)
```

Now my child component looks something like this:

```
const BannerScreen = ({ getMovies }) => {
  
const [json, setJson] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies().then(response => setJson(response));


  }, []);

return (
   <View>       
    {
        json.map(function (movies) {
            return (
                <Text>
                    {movies.title}
                </Text>
            );
        })
    }
</View>
)

}
```

Now how do I fetch the json from my parent and display the content to my child **BannerScreen** based on my API which contains simple movie titles. Also If I press refresh in my parent component, it should refresh the movie list in child component.

Comment: Which component do you want to fetch the movies? `BannerScreen` or the component rendering `BannerScreen`? You pass `getMovies` to both. Can you update your question to include the `BannerScreen` component code?

Comment: Your `return responseData` line in your `getMovies()` function isn't doing anything. Because you're in an asynchronous function, you'll need to look into something called a "callback function" to actually respond to the data you get.

Comment: @DrewReese : I want BannerScreen to get the json from the parent component and loop it to display the titles... I need the function in parent becuase If i press the refresh button , then it must clear the child component and show the latest json

Comment: @jnpdx : hi , i have updated my question  to use callback

Comment: Move the `json` state and `useEffect` into the parent and implement Pulse's answer from below.

Comment: so I should pass the state to the child ?

Comment: Affirmative. The state and logic should be in the parent and state passed down to be rendered.

Comment: so on refresh button I should update the state in parent and it will automatically update the children right ? Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your backend is working fine and returning your titles correctly your "getMovies" function only returns the titles.

You need to create a state in your parent component. for example :

```
const [titles, setTitles] = useState([])
```

and put an asynchronous function in Component that you want to refresh the movies by clicking on it. in that function you first call the getMovies() and store its output into a variable and then update your state.

```
async function updateMovies (){

  const updatedTitles = await getMovies();
  setTitles(updatedTitles)
}
```

finally you pass "titles" state to component that you want to show those titles.

Answer (score 1):

Pass props to child component to update BannerScreen, and also hoist the first fetch in parent component

```
function BannerScreen({ jsonMovies = [] }) {
  return (
    <View>
      {jsonMovies.map(movies => (
        <Text>{movies.title}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

and in the parent component do something like this:

```
function Parent(props) {
  const [jsonMovies, setJsonMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies().then(response => setJsonMovies(response))
  }, [])

  const refreshMovies = async () => {
    try {
      setJsonMovies(await getMovies())
    } catch {
      console.log('show snackbar or some failure component')
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <BannerScreen jsonMovies={jsonMovies} />
      <Pressable onPress={refreshMovies}>
        <Text>Refresh</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}
```